# How to further split string in object for javascript please?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I have two object now

```
obj1-> [ 'logo', 'FinTech startup', 'design' ]
obj2-> [ 'logo', 'tech startup', 'design' ]
```

What is the fastest way to turn them into

```
obj1-> [ 'logo', 'FinTech', 'startup', 'design' ]
obj2-> [ 'logo', 'tech', 'startup', 'design' ]
```

Please?

Thanks!!

Comment: Are obj1 and obj 2 just arrays or are they objects with a named parameter that contains an array?

Comment: `newObj = obj1.join(' ').split(' ');` feel hackish but works

Comment: Please share your code as well. Just showing input and expected output is not good enough.

Comment: @Christopher no they don't have any parameter name..

Comment: @barry-johnson thanks!

Comment: @Rajesh my other code are just counting the number of same value in the 2 object;)

Comment: You bet, I see someone provided the same as answer as well a little after my comment.

Comment: @CarsonYau Its not about other code.It just you are having a problem and you share your input and output. But difference between problem and wish task is the effort that shows where you are stuck and without it its difficult to decide which one is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) and [`Array#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/split) with space.

```js
var array1 = ['logo', 'FinTech startup', 'design'],
    array2 = ['logo', 'tech startup', 'design'];
    
array1 = array1.join(' ').split(' ');
array2 = array2.join(' ').split(' ');

console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I guess `.reduce` can also be used. `result = arr1.reduce((p,c) => p.concat(c.split(" ")))`

Comment: @Rajesh true but it's a lot more iteration and actually doing the opposite of what reduce is meant for (reducing to a single value)